Is it better to use colon instead of semiclolon in 'He likes to talk about himself; that he is a successful businessman...'?
Merriam-webster says:

Semicolons (;) separate independent clauses that are related in
meaning, and they separate items in a list when those items themselves
are long or include commas. For example, this summary could say
"Semicolons are useful; they show that clauses are related in
meaning."
Colons (:) introduce clauses or phrases that serve to describe,
amplify, or restate what precedes them. Often they are used to
introduce a quote or a list that satisfies the previous statement. For
example, this summary could be written as "Colons can introduce many
things: descriptors, quotes, lists, and more."

For "He likes to talk about himself; that he is a successful businessman, and that he is a wealthy man.", when using a semicolon, there should be a complete sentence before and after it, and I think this sentence should either change the semicolon to a colon or take that out.
That is,

He likes to talk about himself: that he is a successful businessman, and that he is a wealthy man.
He likes to talk about himself; he is a successful businessman, and that he is a wealthy man.



He likes to talk about himself; that he is a successful businessman, and that he is a wealthy man.

We don't use the semicolon and the comma this way as the two latter clauses aren't independent.
The suggested version (1) is better. (I have removed the comma.) The part after the colon elaborates the topic:

1a. He likes to talk about himself: that he is a successful businessman and that he is a wealthy man.

Version (2) has three independent clauses joined by a semicolon and a joining comma.
It shouldn't have the complementiser:

2a. He likes to talk about himself; he is a successful businessman, and [ ] he is a wealthy man.

This is not as integrated as version (1).
